# Linking to bsd/stdlib.h

Tags: c, linker, gnu-make

I am not too familiar with how linking works, so apologies ahead of time if I do not have enough detail.

I have installed the bsd library with `sudo apt-get install libbsd-dev` on ubuntu 11.10 I am relatively certain this has been installed, as the man function for heap/mergesort exists (the functions I am looking for)

The C file that I wish to compile has `#include <bsd/stdlib.h>` at the top of the file. I am also `#include <stdlib.h>`.

The Makefile works for other libraries, including time.h gives me `struct timespec`

Is there some error in assuming where apt-get installs libbsd to? Is the second stdlib somehow clashing?

Once again, apologies for the sparse detail.

Code for Makefile below:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-llcthw -lbsd -lrt -ldl  $(OPTLIBS)
LDLIBS=-lbsd -lrt -ldl
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/liblcthw.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

all : $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following patch?
This patch is meant for the Makefile in http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex28.html

```
--- orig/Makefile   2013-11-15 17:58:44.571824670 +0900
+++ Makefile    2013-11-15 17:59:37.315825864 +0900
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
-CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
-LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
+CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc $(shell pkg-config --cflags libbsd) -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
+COMMON_LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs libbsd) -ldl $(OPTLIBS)
+LDLIBS=$(COMMON_LIBS)
 PREFIX?=/usr/local

 SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
@@ -14,7 +15,7 @@
 # The Target Build
 all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

-dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
+dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -Isrc $(shell pkg-config --cflags libbsd) $(OPTFLAGS)
 dev: all

 $(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
@@ -31,7 +32,7 @@

 # The Unit Tests
 .PHONY: tests
-tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
+tests: LDLIBS = $(TARGET) $(COMMON_LIBS)
 tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Is the fix mostly just munging libbsd in the right order so the linker would respond? Or is the fix simply telling the compiler that libbsd is needed? (This was the extra credit assignment on ex35 of LCTHW btw; xubuntu doesn't have merge or heap sort)